# Which class is best to call .getResource on?

Tags: java, comparative-review

I'm creating a [Java Helper Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper) with helpful static methods. I find myself needing to call `...getResource(...)` or `...getResourceAsStream(...)` in several instances and I'm wondering what's the best practice for this. It seems to be working fine when I say: `Helper.class.getResource(...)`, but I'm wondering whether that will bite me in the future.

I have a few alternatives I'm thinking of. Below is an example of when I need to use this and the alternatives I have thought of:

**Alternative 1** (what I would prefer for the sake of users):

```
/**
* Takes the given resource and returns that as a string.
*
* @param location of the file
* @return the file as a string
* @throws IOException
*/
public static String resourceToString(String location) throws IOException {
  InputStream is = IOHelper.class.getResourceAsStream(location);
  InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
  return readerToString(r);
}
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
/**
* Takes the given resource (based on the given class) and returns that as a string.
*
* @param location of the file
* @param c class to get the resource from
* @return the file as a string
* @throws IOException
*/
public static String resourceToString(String location, Class c) throws IOException {
  InputStream is = c.getResourceAsStream(location);
  InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
  return readerToString(r);
}
```

**Alternative 3** (should I just have the user give me the resource?):

```
/**
* Takes the given InputStream and returns that as a string.
*
* @param is the InputStream of the File to read
* @return the file as a string
* @throws IOException
*/
public static String resourceToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
  InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
  return readerToString(r);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer the second one. The others will bite if the library runs inside an OSGi container.

Furthermore, I would

1. pass `UTF-8` character encoding to the constructor of the `InputStreamReader`. Otherwise it will use the system encoding which vary from system to system. (Or let the user to set it with a third method parameter.)
2. use longer variable names. `is`, `r`, `c` are not too easy to read. I would call them `resourceStream`, `clazz` and `resourceReader`. It does not force readers to decode them.
3. reverse the order of `String location, Class c` parameters. It would be in the same order as the first line use them (`c.getResourceAsStream(location)`). I don't know if there is a rule of thumb for this, but it looks more natural to me. (Any pointers are welcome.)
4. remove the `* @throws IOException` javadoc line. It is meaningless in this form.